# AngularFire with multiple children

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to create a firebase parent with multiple children. I looked into the documentation and I can't figure how to create many children in parallel level of my board child.

```
@unbind() if @unbind
@id = @uniqueId()
@dbRef = new Firebase url + "#{@id}"
@db = @$firebase @dbRef.child('board')

@db.$bind( @$scope, 'cells' ).then (unbind) =>
  @unbind = unbind
```

This is my code so far.

```
tictactoe-lau
  5e776bvj
    board
      0: value
      3: value
      4: value
      5: value
      6: value
      7: value
```

This is the structure of my current db. I want `5e776bvj` to have additional children, parallel to the `board` level.

Comment: Hi Marco, what does your data look like?

Comment: ^Agreed, hard to help with 'children' when we don't know about the 'parents'.

Comment: Hello, I added my current db structure. I want the unique ID to have more children. So far, I know how to set one child for it.